# ListPicker TwoWay Binding and itemsource

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I try to build settings page to my Windows Phone 8 app, the settings page has couple of ListPickers. The basic idea has been taken from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769510(v=vs.105).aspx

In my settings page xaml I have just declared:

```xml
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPicker1" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" SelectionMode="Single" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource generalListPickerFullTemplate}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource generalListPickerTemplate}" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource appSettings}, Path=listPicker1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In "code behind", I create list and set it item source to listPicker1

```c#
listPicker1List.Add(new ListPickerItem() { name = "First value", value = "value_1" });
listPicker1List.Add(new ListPickerItem() { name = "Second value", value = "value_2" });
this.listPicker1.ItemsSource = listPicker1List;
```

StaticResource `appSettings` points to class which is basically similar than in the MS example,

```c#
public ListPickerItem listPicker1
{
    get
    {
        return GetValueOrDefault<ListPickerItem>(KeyName, Default);
    }

    set
    {
        if (AddOrUpdateValue(KeyName, value))
        {
            Save();
        }
    }
}
```

So is it not possible to set itemsource and use two way bindig? If I set these both, I get `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Basically my only goal is to have listPicker with items, which have text to display for user and value. And to easily set and get these to Isolates storage.

Answer (score 0):

You have this error when you set itemsource or select an item?

Comment: When I set the item source, I get the exception. Or if I remove the SelectedItem... binding it works fine.